# New mac (High Sierrra), can't reach localhost, local client sites or phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, macos, apache, phpmyadmin

I just upgraded to a new mac, but can't reach localhost, local client sites and phpmyadmin. I'm sure I missed something, but so far, I've verified that:

1. /etc/hosts files are exactly the same
2. /etc/my.cnf files are exactly
   the same
3. /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file are exactly the same
4. /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf are exactly the same

Permissions on the files agree to the old mac permissions

MySQL works fine after recreating a mysql symbolic link in usr/local. I can see and manipulate databases via MySQLWorkbench.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: is the webserver process running?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just needed to restart apache using sudo apachectl restart. I would have thought the numerous machine reboots would have negated the need for this, but I'm happy now that I'm back up and running.